# Adding an element to a rdd depending on a calculation on the same rdd

Tags: python, pyspark

I am new to Python `spark` so this question might be elementary. However, I could not find any good answer here or on Google so I will just ask it anyway.

I want add some elements to my rdd depending on some calculation I do on that rdd. Lets say my rdd is named lines and contains a string. I want to add two numbers which is tab separated together in the file. Then add this sum at the end of the lines rdd.

```
lines = sc.textFile("myFile.txt")
#Splitting the string where there are tabs
linesArr=lines.map(lambda line: line.split("\t"))
```

Now I want to add together the two first tabs in `linesArr` and add the result at the end of lines.

How do I do this?

Comment: I managed to add together the two first elements by using: theSum=linesArr(lambda x: sumFunction(x[0]+x[1]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you who might wonder about the same thing here is how I solved it with a simple example:

```
n=sc.parallelize([(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9)])

m=n.map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1])

z=n.zip(m).map(lambda x: (x[0][0],x[0][1],x[1]))
```

The result z is: [(1,1,2),(2,2,4),...]
Note that if one omit the map the result will be [((1,1),2),((2,2),4),..] and I did not want that in this case.